# Why 'Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0'?

Tags: node.js, ssms, loopback

I'm using loopback in order to create an api with MSSQL. I have used a tutorial and although I have done all steps, it returns me this when i run the server.js file..

```
 Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0

 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:27)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at loadModelDefinition (C:\Users\M\cile\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:470:20)
    at C:\Users\M\cile\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:363:21
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\M\cile\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:361:8
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at findModelDefinitions (C:\Users\M\cile\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:348:11)
    at buildAllModelInstructions (C:\Users\M\cile\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:225:16)
    at compile (C:\Users\M\cile\node_modules\loopback-boot\lib\compiler.js:106:27)
    at bootLoopBackApp (C:\Users\M\cile\node_modules\loopback-boot\index.js:153:22)
```

Can you please say me what's wrong?

Here is the model-config code:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Hello": {
    "dataSource": "mySqlServer",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

And here's the .json file code in common file

```
module.exports = function(hello) { 

};
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to load the file beginning with `module.exports` as a JSON file - that *isn't* JSON, it's Javascript. It's not clear to me what you mean by "And here's the .json file code in common file" but it's not JSON.

Comment: @JonSkeet  thank you SO much!!It worked!